# Error "File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it"

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my project to the latest Play services `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'`. I am also using the latest version of playservices in my app.gradle file as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

However when I compile, Gradle throws exception as follows

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You need to get the **configuration file** from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your project.

**Update:**

Goto

1. https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Select your project
3. On the left menu, click on settings > project settings
4. Add an app or download the google-services.json file under the *Your Apps* section.

Comment: what is "app level" that you mean?

Comment: The app ran for me after going to the link above. Here's a screenshot of where I placed the config file "google-services.json" https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPvO2TtHNQhmyeUfM7qJ8e899vulbqB28h-VbOKsqe1XorsoI36huhnbQBOnTvpqw/photo/AF1QipPHRtAV62Tw1PdMw_EZQtGtAdhrFs8GhG8jZvcE?key=eFgyeFpDTnZuNlY0Um84ZWNTT3Vha1VOaW5odEpB

Comment: I have generated the file and also filled in the build.grade at root level and app level, but still get the same error on a gradle build ?

Comment: I am using ionic and in my case it had to put inside platform/andriod/app

Comment: For **Flutter** it has to be in `[project root]/android/app/google-services.json`

Comment: anyone know if this file is safe to commit or does it need to be treated secret and injected during CI/CD?  Seems like `client.api_key.current_key` is sensitive buts not clear how it's being used.  The docs dont seem to treat it as such.  :shrug:

Comment: It is not secret but contains unique identifiers.

Comment: My google-services.json is in my android/app/ but build still can't find it.

Answer (score 124):

Please go to this URL :

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Choose your Options and  finally you will be able to download

`google-service.json` file

copy that file and paste it Into

`YourProjectName/app`  Directory

Then recompile the project Most probably it will fly

In my case the project directory looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 36):

For anyone using **Firebase** you need to go into your console and there it should say "add project to Android". From there, it will step-by-step generate the google-services.json file for you.

Comment: i found the setup instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 24):

in my case i have saved a json file with a space like this

> google-services .json

and the right one is

> google-services.json

and also take care you do not put (_) instead of (-)

may help some one.

Answer (score 22):

I received this error while trying to run Google's Firebase analytics sample app:

**Prerequisites:**

- Download https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android
- Add quickstart/analytics to Android Studio

**Add Procedure:**

1. Go to https://firebase.google.com/
2. Click on "GO TO CONSOLE"
3. Click on "Add Project"
4. Project name: Enter: sample-app
5. Click "Create Project"
   [Takes about 10 seconds or so...]
6. Click "Continue"
7. On the "Getting Started" page, click "Add Firebase to your Android app"
8. Enter package name for the android app 
    [The full package name appears at the top of the manifest: "com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics"]
9. Click on download google-services.json
10. In file explorer, add google-services.json to the directory: 
     "quickstart/analytics/app"
     [Warning: Do not rename the file, it must be: google-services.json]
11. Run 'app'

    - The sample app already contains the necessary Gradle file settings.
    - When adding a new project do: Tools -> Firebase -> Analytics -> Add 
      Event -> Connect App to Firebase.
    - Adding a project via Android Studio ensures that all the Gradle Dependecies are setup.

**Remove Procedure:**

1. Go to https://firebase.google.com/
2. Click on "GO TO CONSOLE"
3. Settings -> Project Settings -> Delete this App
4. Settings -> Project Settings -> Delete Project
5. Enter project ID and press delete

I added and removed the sample app multiple times without any noticeable side effects.

Comment: Since AndroidStudio 3.0 you can use Firebase assistant from Tools->Firebase

Answer (score 13):

If you don't need it anymore…

**…\build.gradle:**

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

->

// classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

**…\app\build.gradle:**

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

->

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Thanks! This is useful when you download the source code of an app available at Google Play and you want to run it locally. I disabled this and another plugin with this method.

Comment: you're gonna face problems if you need google play services registered for your app for example in push notifications, your push type will be empty instead of gms because your app is not registered as a user of google play services

Answer (score 8):

You must go on ***Firebase console-->Settings-->Project Settings*** and there will be section with ***Download the latest config file***. Download google-service.json and put into app folder. It's work for me. 
Links:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: Define "app folder".

Comment: Under **projects-settings**, we need to **ADD APP** and it will generate a `google-services.json` file that can be downloaded and added to `<appName>/platforms/<platformName>/google-services.json`.

Good Luck...

Answer (score 6):

I just run into problem downloading `google-services.json` from Firebase console. Turns out I had to log out from all other google accounts than the one I was using for Firebase.

Comment: What do you mean log out from other accounts ? Did you need to log out on the device or the browser ?

Comment: I am usually logged in to multiple Google accounts at once in the browser (you can see them in top right corner of any Google site). I had to log out from all of them except the one used for Firebase before it started working.

Answer (score 6):

### For `Cordova Apps`:

We need to place the `google-services.json` file in `app root` (I believe; when working with Cordova apps, we are not to get into other folders/files such as Gradle, Java files, platforms, etc; instead only work with them VIA the `config.xml`  and `www` folder) and refer it in the `config.xml` like so:

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- Add this line -->
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

#### NOTE: Ensure that the `Firebase App packagename` is same as the `id` attribute in `<widget id="<packagename>" ... >` are same.

For ex:

```
<!-- config.xml of Cordova App -->
<widget id="com.appFactory.torchapp" ...>

<!--google-serivces.json from generated from Firebase console.-->
{
  ...
  packagename: "com.appFactory.torchapp",
  ...
}
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.google.com/android/ 
you need to generate configuration file which gives you access to all the services and APIs you registered for in developer console and place it in your root directory

Comment: Well, this is really strange, i didn't need any of the services displayed. But still needed to activate one to get the json file..

Comment: If you are not using any of the services, may I know why this dependency is being included in the project ?

Comment: The list of services proposed by Google are : Sign In, Cloud Messaging, Analytics, App Invite, Admob. If i just want to use the Location service, i still need to have the configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

In android studio:

1. switch to Project view so you can see the actual project folder structure.
2. find google-services.json file and drag it to the app directory (for some reason when I added it using file explorer, it put it in the gradle folder).
3. Clean/Rebuild project.

It worked fine for me from there.

Answer (score 4):

> Easiest way to add google-service.json file

In Android Studio follow these steps:

Click **Tools > Firebase** to open the **Assistant** window.

Click to expand one of the listed features (for example, Analytics), then click the Get Started tutorial to connect to Firebase and add the necessary code to your app.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The problem is because of renaming the file. You might have downloaded N number of google-services.json files in your downloads folder. So when you download a new file it will download with same name but by adding numeric values in brackets. something like google-services(1).json .So you have to delete this (1) and copy the file. Make sure when you are renaming it, there should not be any spaces or extra . in the name of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the configuration file from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your current project.

Answer (score 3):

Very Simple
Just go to Tools->Firebase->Connect to firebase than click on sync now
THIS WILL SURELY WORK.

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' add this must

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools-->Firebase in your Android Studio and click on Connect your app to Firebase. They will set it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the Firebase of the project, for example, you downloaded an example source code then you have to remove any Firebase related stuff to make the project run.

Search keywords in the project

- List item
- fabric
- firebase
- google-services
- crashlytics

Answer (score 1):

Even after adding all the dependencies and the file if you face any such problem it could be your incorrect file name of "google-services.json".

Make sure you have the exact file name without any additional spaces or characters.

I had renamed the file and had space" " in my filename which was not noticeable, later I found that my file name is wrong, so fixed it!.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

select get started and go to settings logo and then project settings
after that you will see below the platform like web,android,ios . select that according to your preference.
and then download 
google-service.json file

copy that file and paste it Into

YourProjec/app    Directory
and then finally sync again .

Answer (score 0):

That Problem is because:- The folder or file you pasted to your product downloaded from the firebase console is not named as google-services.json. so now click it then right mouse click in all the options open refractor and rename it to google-services.json. because this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Had faced same issue ..

well in my case i have saved

> google-services.json

as

> google_services.json

I tried every solution mentioned above but nothing helps...
the error was instead of "_" you need to put "-"(dash).

Just refactoring the file to ***google-services.json*** from ***google_services.json*** works like charm..

Hope this helps!!!

P.S. I know it's sound silly but this only works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Navigate to your project folder and open the /app sub-folder.
2. Paste the .json file here.
3. Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

for people coming here from the firebase codelabs tutorial step 3:go to page 4.

Apparently, if google says `You should now have the android-start project open in Android Studio.` ,She means it,and not `You should now have the android-start project open in Android Studio, without any  build-errors` .
 As the instruction says there, you have to get a configuration file from firebase. i.e , create a new project in your firebase acc with name 'friendly chat and in the next page , add its `package name` and `SHA1 KEY.`
 after downloading the json file,add it to your `project>app` folder, and Rebuild project.