# File google-services.json is missing from module root folder (but it is at the good place ! )

Tags: android, json, google-maps, gradle

I try to use google sign in in my android app, i read the page https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating and i made all steps, now i put my google-services.json in my app folder, and after downloading the google-services.json, i do :

```
mv Dowloads/google-services.json AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/
```

so, when i do :

```
ls AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/
app.iml  build  build.gradle  google-services.json  libs  proguard-rules.pro  src
```

My file google-services.json seems to be at the good place,but gradle console displays an error :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I read [Error "File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google-service) but it isn't my probleme because my file is at the good place.

ps : And sorry for my bad english ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add these line of codes in Gradle files if you haven't already. 
In Module:app_name gradle file, add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

on top of the file. And in dependencies of the same file, add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Also, in Project:project_name gradle file, add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

in dependencies

Also, try to upload a screenshot of the stack trace if this doesn't repair your problem

Answer (score -2):

download google-service.json file 
copy that file and paste it Into YourProjectName/app Directory