# google-services.json file already added, but getting an error : File google-services.json is missing from module root folder

Tags: android, json, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I try to configuration android developer console and download the **google-services.json** file. Now I put my google-services.json in my **app** folder, then build project, but gradle console displays an error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Perhaps see this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google-service)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add google-services.json file into app folder of your project.
Read this [article](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#introduction) from official documentation.
Get your google-service.json file [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add).