# Android Studio & firebase issues

Tags: java, android

hello guys can someone help me find solution to this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     /Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/HaveChat/app/src/debug/google-services.json
>     /Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/HaveChat/app/google-services.json

in my build gradle i have adde this code

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.0'

and i have also i applied this plugin as well

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

but yet still am getting that error. thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to download **google-services.json** File

complete setup guide from this link

[Click here..](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: thank you for helping out but i downloaded the google-services.json File and i have copied and paste it but still the issue is not solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Studio's Firebase assistant to automatically connect your project to a respective one on Firebase OR to create a new one and then connect to it if you don't have a Firebase project already.

[image: Firebase option in "Tools" menu][image: Connect option]