# Google Services Plugin cannot function without google-services.json

Tags: android, json, android-studio, google-signin, google-authentication

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function

I get this error code since I deleted my `google-services.json` file from my project. Now the obvious way to solve this issue would be to include it again, but I had a reason to remove it.

"[Note: If you enabled only Google Sign-In when you generated the configuration file, you can skip this step. Google Sign-In does not require the configuration file to be included in your project—generating the file performs the neecessary configuration steps.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#horzTab)" - this is the official note in the documentation and since **I only enabled Google Sign-In** I don't see a reason for this error message. Does anyone have had this problem too and a solve to it because I think that I implemented everything correctly.

*Note: It works **with** the file in the project included.*

**EDIT:** To clarify, my application works completely fine and I have no problems, but I wondered why I cannot remove the google-services.json file even though I should be able to do it with no problem!

Comment: Just clarifying. You are only using google sign in and not firebase right ?

Comment: Have you added plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of your app/build.gradle

Comment: I updated my question. This does not in any way answer it, sorry if I my question was poorly written.

Comment: Yes @JaswanthManigundan Also when I sign in, I don't have to allow anything, so I am not even requesting Email or similar, just plain sign in.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` inside your app-level `build.gradle` it parses configuration information from the `google-services.json` file.

You removed `google-services.json` file, that's why it is not able to parse
 So remove the below line too from your app-level `build.gradle` who triggered parsing to make it work again.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: According to your requirement(`Google Sign-In`), you don't need to send/parse `.json` data so remove it.

Comment: You are a genius man!! saved a lot of time... thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to copy my google-service.json file into project and I was wonder why it's not working. Thaks once again

Answer (score 1):

You are using Google signin right? So u definitely need a google-services.json file

Refer this link

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I actually don't need it. See @AbhishekAryan's anwser.

Answer (score 1):

The gradle-plugin google-services that is referenced by classpath and with apply is a build-time plugin only! So it only influences the build-process of your app, but not the runtime-process!
Thats why your app is working fine but google-services json is required.

Comment: This only lacked the explanation on how to fix the issue / use Google Signin without the json file.