# Android firebase database connectivity error

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting below error in my project.

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Retrive\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\Retrive\app\google-services.json
```

Comment: Have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968332/5110595)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google

Answer (score 2):

You need to download google-services.json file from firebase console and put it in app folder to solve the issue as google-services plugin need this file for its functioning as error conveys.

And if you are not using any google-services than you may remove the line, of applying the google-services plugin at the end of app level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

> The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

you getting this error because you didn't download json file from firebase server.
 So not just at the root, but also at a specific path under it, e.g. **/users,** **/users/charlinagnes,** etc.

Download  `google-services.json` file from `firebase` console and put it into your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to get the configuration file from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your project.**