# The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. File google-services.json is missing.

Tags: android-studio

File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\balcony\balcony\Module_SDK\google-services.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google)

Answer (score 0):

**just change in the build.gradle the line**

```
compile fileTree (dir: 'libs', include: ['* .jar'])
```

**to**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

and ready, your mistake will be corrected!