# Error when passing an app to my Huawei - Android-studio - Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, emulation

hello I’m trying to pass by my first made an application(flutter) to my phone(Huawei) but gives me a strange error someone has already gone through the same, can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

ERROR:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ALE L21 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/src/nullnull/google-services.json
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/src/nullnullDebug/google-services.json
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/src/nullnull/debug/google-services.json
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/src/debug/nullnull/google-services.json
  /Users/indumonta/AndroidStudioProjects/smarthouse/android/app/google-services.json
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear. Your `google-services.json` is missing.

Comment: hello I know, but I don’t know how to solve my app needs it

Comment: You're likely using a Google service and didn't completely follow or properly follow the setup instructions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google