# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm using the Timestamp class from **cloud_firestore** to convert DateTime value from a formfield when I post the form.

Here is my function for converting the selected date of the formfield:

```
    int convertDate(DateTime date) {
    var convertedDate = int.parse(Timestamp.fromDate(date).millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
    return convertedDate;
}
```

And here is where I use this function in the `onPressed` function of my form button:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35),
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){postTimes(convertDate(selectedDate), convertTime(_timeController.text));},
                child: Text("Save")
            ),
        )
    ],
)
```

It worked **fine** the first times I used it with the cloud_firestore package.

But when I reopened my code the day after and launched it I got this error:

***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')***

So I added **firebase** and **firebase_core** packages, and this :

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

in my index.html file like said in the tutorials.

Now, I get this error:

***FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).***

I made my `main()` asynchronous and added these lines:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

just as advised in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in).

Right now, I'm still getting the error and don't know how to fix it,

If anyone can help,

Thanks,

Comment: Also, I precise that thanks to the answer of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google) I made it works with my Android emulator, but I still get the same issue when I want to run my app in the browser.

Comment: Can you also show your dependencies? As per this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/258#issuecomment-418842537), load order matters.

Comment: In my main.dart : import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; In the file where I use the Timestamp class from firestore :  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Comment: Try one of the examples from the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in?rq=1).