# Flutter is not running

Tags: flutter

I am tying to run flutter on android studio, I do not know if this part is relevant or not, but I have this weird error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /home/alex/StudioProjects/ictproject/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /home/alex/StudioProjects/ictproject/android/app/src/google-services.json
  /home/alex/StudioProjects/ictproject/android/app/src/Debug/google-services.json
  /home/alex/StudioProjects/ictproject/android/app/google-services.json


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I do not know what to do, if you have any suggestion please tell me.

I think I found the problem but I am not sure, I did a "flutter doctor" and those are the results:

```html
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-56-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866127/2804581

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are missing the `cmdline-tools` component in your Android SDK, and the Android SDK licenses have not been accepted. You can resolve this issue by following these steps:

1. First, you need to install `cmdline-tools`. You can do this by using the `sdkmanager`, which is a command line tool that allows you to view, install, update, and uninstall packages for the Android SDK. To do this, you need to run the following command:

   ```
   path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
   ```

   You should replace `path/to/sdkmanager` with the path where your `sdkmanager` is installed. If you are unsure where it is, you may need to search for it on your machine.

   Note that to run the above command, you need to have the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable set, which is where the Android SDK is installed on your machine. You also need to have your Android platform's `PATH` updated to include `tools` and `platform-tools`.
2. After installing `cmdline-tools`, you need to accept the Android SDK licenses. You can do this by running the following command:

   ```
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   ```

   This command will present all licenses that have not been accepted and ask you to accept them. Press `y` to accept each license when prompted.
3. After following the above steps, run `flutter doctor` again to check if all issues have been resolved:

   ```
   flutter doctor
   ```

I hope this solves your problem!